# examine stripping out search words

Tags: search, umbraco, lucene.net

I'm using umbraco and I have examine up and running however my query is having words stripped out

For example:

I am searching on "man on the moon" with the following line of code, the variable "searchTerm" should contain "man on the moon":

```
var Searcher = ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["MySearcher"];
var searchCriteria = Searcher.CreateSearchCriteria();

var query = searchCriteria.Field("Name", searchTerm).Compile();
```

however, the query is generated as this when I debug:

```
{ SearchIndexType: , LuceneQuery: +Name:"man moon" }
```

Notice how it has removed the words "on the" from the searchTerm?

Presumably these are because they are deemed as STOP/reserved words. However, this means I do not get the search results I expect.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 2):

Internally the StopAnalyzer class is used by the StandardAnalyzer as part of the standard indexing process.  The StopAnalyzer  (http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d7/df5/_stop_analyzer_8cs_source.html#l00054) contains a method which allows you to substitute a different set of stopwords as an ISet type parameter rather than use the standard ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET (line 134).

And I read here (http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:sA-uyAC015UJ:our.umbraco.org/m%3Fmode%3Dtopic%26id%3D25600+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk) that you can get Examine to use an empty set of stopwords by adding the following line to your application_start method in global.asax

```
Lucene.Net.Analysis.StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
```

So with an empty set of stopwords your man in the moon should be back.

A bit of an odd idea but as an alternative you could also add a StopAnalyzer to ExamineSettings.config to create an index of docs with only the stop words and then AND them with your standardanalyzer result set?